# Adding array key in a PHP multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I am having problems updating a deeply nested multidimensional php associative array.
What I basically want it to add and 'parent_id' key with an incrementing value to all array elements that has an array under them.

For example i have the array below.

```
   [root] =>
    Array('child_1' =>
            Array('child1_grandchild_1' => 'gchild1_value',
                  'child1_grandchild_2' =>  Array('grandchild_1' => 'gchildval1',
                                                  'grandchild_2  => 'gchildval2',
                                                  'grandchild_3' => 'gchildval3'),
                  'child1_grandchild_3' => 'gchild3_value'),
    'child_2', =>  Array('child2_grandchild_1' => 'gchildval1',             
                         'child2_grandchild_2' => 'gchildval2'),
    'child_3'  => 'child3_val',
    'child_4'  => 'child4_val'
    );
```

I want to to add a parent key id element for elements with array values. 
Basically, the array above will transform into the array below. But I don't know how to do this considering I don't know how deeply nested the array is.
I tried passing the array by reference by updating it doesn't work.

```
   [root] =>
    Array( 'parent_id' => 1
           'child_1' =>
            Array('child1_grandchild_1' => 'gchild1_value',
                  'child1_grandchild_2' =>  Array('parent_id' => 2,
                                                  'grandchild_1' => 'gchildval1',
                                                  'grandchild_2  => 'gchildval2',
                                                  'grandchild_3' => 'gchildval3'),
                  'child1_grandchild_3' => 'gchild3_value'),
    'child_2', =>  Array('parent_id' => 3,
                         'child2_grandchild_1' => 'gchildval1',             
                         'child2_grandchild_2' => 'gchildval2'),
    'child_3'  => 'child3_val',
    'child_4'  => 'child4_val'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?
Your item keys will start at 1000. If you have more items then 1000 in each branch then add a zero make it 10000 or whatever is safe.

```
$no = 1000;
$no2 = 1;

function addpid(&$item, $key)
{
        global $no;
        global $no2;
        if(is_array($item)){
            $item['parent_id'] = $no;
            $no++;
        }else{
            $no2++;
            $no=$no2*1000;
        }
}

$yourarray

array_walk_recursive($yourarray, 'addpid');
```

Comment: I tried this one, but $item is not recognized. It can only see the $key value. My array is an multidimensional associative from a json file.